# Javascript transition

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wrote an javascript code that slides the viewport from one link to another.
Basicaly all works fine how you can see there http://jsfiddle.net/DruwJ/8/

my problem now is that i want to stop the viewport slide when the link

```
<input id="bottom" type="button" value="Midlle" onclick="smoothScrollTo(0, 500)">
```

is at the bottom of the vieport and not at the top.

I hope somebody knows the solution! (Im a beginner in javascript)

Thanks!

Comment: It's actually just a coincidence that the scrolling is going so that the middle button is at the top; try widening the jsfiddle viewport and scrolling, you'll see that it stops with that button in the middle somewhere.

Comment: its no coincidence, when i wide the viewport the document is shorter, so that the scrolling ends at the bottom of the page!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I could do without jQuery was:

```
onclick="smoothScrollTo(document.getElementById('bottom').offsetTop + 30 - window.innerHeight)"
```

I'm assuming you want the bottom of the button aligned with the bottom of the page. And not the top of the button aligned with the bottom of the page.

The key point here is subtracting the window.innerHeight to have the button at the bottom. I'm adding 30 as an approximation for the height of the button. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with how to get the height of a button without jQuery's help. I suggest using jQuery in your project to make all DOM manipulation more stable and friendly.

Alternatively, you could add some dummy div/element right below the button, and have the system scroll to that.

```
onclick="smoothScrollTo(document.getElementById('dummy').offsetTop - window.innerHeight)"
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/DruwJ/10/

Comment: how can i achieve it that he deduct 100% of the vieport? The thing is that my whole site has an height of 300% and every panel has his link to the next site, one panel has the height of 100%                     it should look like this, but my code is not right:                            smoothScrollTo(document.getElementById('dummy').offsetTop - 100%)"

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: sorry, im german! Ok i want that he scrolls down from the actual viewport 100%. Maybe you can understand this:             onclick="smoothScrollTo(-100%)                                          You are awesome! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok thanks, finally i had the solution                                var viewportHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;
smoothScrollTo(document.getElementById('bottom').offsetTop - viewportHeight )